# OpenSSL + Passenger + RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, rvm

I believe I've got this setup correctly for the most part but I'm having trouble getting my site to pick up the ssl certificate that I created with OpenSSL.

I've install my ruby version with rvm using with openssl option to set the openssl path:

`rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`

Then I followed these instructions: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Step 5 was different because I copied the key and cert files to the openssl domain in the `.rvm` directory.

I then set `config.force_ssl` to `true` in my `production.rb` file.

I set my hosting to enable ssl as well.

Finally I restarted the server. I'm able to go to https://mysite.com but I warns me that the site has insecure content.

Not sure what to do from here. Any help or direction would be great.

Comment: Does it say that the site is insecure, or that it there is secure and insecure content on the page?  Often browsers will throw a warning when there are resources being called using anything but https.  A common culprit is external js and css files.

Comment: Okmthats good to know. It says insecure content. What should I do if I'm using external cdn us? Thanks.

Comment: Your CDN can usually point you to the correct solution, but it would generally involve calling your resources with https rather than http.  If the hostname for your CDN is set somewhere in the rails options, you can often just append https:// to make it work.

Comment: Each of them had https as well. Thanks! - You should make your comment and answer so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CDN can usually point you to the correct solution, but it would generally involve calling your resources with https rather than http. If the hostname for your CDN is set somewhere in the rails options, you can often just prepend `https://` to make it work